# JavaScript event handler click thumbnail to enlarge image

Tags: javascript, html

So I am very new to Web Design and am having issues getting my click event handler to work.I cant change the html or css files. My task is to set a click handler to my thumbnails to enlarge the image in the img within the `<figure>` element. While also setting the figcaption text in the figure to the thumbs title attribute. I need to attach to the div id = thumbnails. My script is not enlarging my thumbnails or titles.

This is my created HTML Doc:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head >
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Chapter 9 - Share Your Travels</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chapter09-project02.js">
        </script>   
`      `</head>
        <body>
        <header>
        <h2>Share Your Travels</h2>
        <nav><img src="images/menu.png"></nav>
        </header>
        <main>
        <figure id="featured">
        <img src="images/medium/5855774224.jpg" title="Battle" />
        <figcaption>Battle</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div id="thumbnails">
        <img src="images/small/5855774224.jpg" title="Battle"/>
        <img src="images/small/5856697109.jpg" title="Luneburg"/>
        <img src="images/small/6119130918.jpg" title="Bermuda" />
        <img src="images/small/8711645510.jpg" title="Athens" />
        <img src="images/small/9504449928.jpg" title="Florence" />
        </div>

        </main>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Js script:

```
       var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
       thumbs.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

       if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
            var clickedImageSource = e.target.src;


       var newSrc = clickedImageSource.replace("small", "medium");           


       var featuredImage = document.querySelector("#featured img");
       featuredImage.src = newSrc;
       featuredImage.title = e.target.title;

        }

        });

       var img = document.getElementById("figcaption");
       img.addEventListener("mouseover",function (event) {
       img.className = "featured figcaption";
       });
       img.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
       img.className = "featured figcaption";

       var element = document.getElementById('figcaption');
       element.style.opacity = "0.9";
       element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=0%)';


        });
```

Thanks for any advice and hopefully I can pay it forward for someone else!

Comment: Errors in the console?  Your event handler looks ok maybe the problem is the timing of when the script gets loaded - if the “Js script” script is being loaded in the head it won’t work because the thumbnails div doesn’t exist yet.  But you would see a console error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it causes you the problem. The JS is getElementById, but there's no ID is call figcaption.

```
var img = document.getElementById("figcaption");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `getElementById` to find something with the id of `figcaption`; nothing on the page has an id of `figcaption`, so `getElementById` returns `null`.

There are a few ways you could fix it:

- Add an id to your `<figcaption>` element: `<figcaption id="figcaption">`
- Instead of using `getElementById`, use `getElementsByTagName`: `document.getElementsByTagName('figcaption')[0];`. (`getElementsByTagName` always returns a collection of elements, the `[0]` grabs the first, and in this case only, one in the collection).
- Instead of using `getElementById`, use `querySelector` like you did to find the featured image element: `document.querySelector("#featured figcaption");`

This last approach of using `querySelector` is what I would recommend in this situation; other times it might be better to add an id to the element.

```js
const thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
const featuredImage = document.querySelector("#featured img");
const caption = document.querySelector("#featured figcaption");

thumbs.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
    var clickedImageSource = e.target.src;
    
    // for the purposes of this demo, I'm using a placeholder
    // image service so I need to change the size slightly differently
    let newSrc = clickedImageSource.replace("50x50", "350x150");
    //var newSrc = clickedImageSource.replace("small", "medium");

    featuredImage.src = newSrc;
    caption.textContent = e.target.title;
  }
});


caption.addEventListener("mouseover",function (event) {
  caption.className = "featured figcaption";
});
caption.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
  caption.className = "featured figcaption";
  // I changed the value to .5 instead of .9 because with such small
  // text the opacity change is barely perceivable.
  caption.style.opacity = "0.5";
  // This is not needed, this was the old way IE used to do it,
  // IE < 9 needed it, but IE < 9 is no longer relevant. Just use opacity.
  //element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=0%)';
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Share Your Travels</h2>
  <nav><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=Menu"></nav>
</header>
<main>
  <figure id="featured">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" title="Battle">
    <figcaption>Battle</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div id="thumbnails">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" title="Battle">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000/ffffff" title="Luneburg">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/00ff00/ffffff" title="Bermuda">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0000ff/ffffff" title="Athens">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/000000/ffffff" title="Florence">
  </div>
</main>
```

A few things to note about my version, I used [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Both [`let`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) and [`const`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=const) are well supported these days and should be used instead of `var` unless you need to support very old browsers. I also only query for the caption and featured image elements once and store them in the scope above the click handler, this allows the code inside the click handler to have access to them via [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). This makes everything slightly more efficient since you don't have to query the DOM to find them each time the click handler runs. In this case the performance gain is moot but it is good to be in the habit of writing code as efficiently as possible so you don't have to think about it when it does matter.

Images are [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements), meaning they can't have any content, so you don't need a closing tag. For this reason I used bare `<img>` tags instead of [self-closing](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31857/self-closing-tag) `<img />` tags. Self-closing images were only ever needed in [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), since it was [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), which has a more rigid syntax than HTML. Another thing to note, you [don't need the `type="text/javascript"`](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/#code-that-might-be-bad) on your `<script>` tags, it just takes up extra space and doesn't really do anything.

I don't understand what you are trying to do with the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers. Currently what your code does is:

- When the mouse moves over the caption, the `featured` and `figcaption` classes are added to the caption.
- When the mouse leaves the caption, the `featured` and `figcaption` classes are again added to the caption and its opacity is set to `0.9`, effectively permanently.

I cleaned it up a little in my example to make it more obvious that is what is happening.